# Sitecore string field as literal in XSL? Trying to use sc:field as img source

Tags: xml, xslt, sitecore, field, string-literals

I have a string field in Sitecore that I am trying to use as the source for an image tag in an xsl file. This is what I've got:

```
<xsl:if test="sc:fld('logo url', $sc_currentitem) != ''">
  <img src="{???}" />
</xsl:if>
```

But I don't know what to put in the src. I need to set it to the value of the "logo url" field.

edit: I set it to `<img src="{sc:fld('logo url',.,'src')}" />` based on [this article](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XSL/Accessing%20Field%20Values/Image.aspx), but the image isn't displaying. I know that the field is populated.

Comment: Did you try the Sitecore xsl control?  -e.g. <sc:image field="My Image"/>   It's been a while, but I don't believe the image tag will render if there is no value.

Comment: That doesn't work because it's a string field, not an image field

Answer (score 0):

Turns out just removed 'src' worked:

```
<img src="{sc:fld('logo url',.)}" />
```